# No set can belong to itself ( axiom of regularity)

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

But let  $X=\{ \text{any object } x : x \text{ is not a laptop}\}$. We get that $X$ is a set (by the definition of set)
and also $X$ is an object (as $X$ is not a laptop)
So,  $X$ is in $X$,  how??

Comment: If $X$ were a set then $X\cup\{x:x \textrm{ is a laptop}\}=Y$ the universal class, would be a set, which it is not. In general, the universal complement of a set is not a set.

Comment: Is the collection of all things not inside of a laptop, something that is not inside of laptop?

Comment: What do you mean by the definition of "set"? There is no such definition in standard set theory...

Comment: A well-defined collection of distinct object or idea is called a set. Observation,  by the word well-defined we mean there is no ambiguity regarding inclusion or exclusion of any object.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is your "definition" of set. How do you define a set? You are trying to argue mathematically about an object which you call set but whose definition is not mathematical whatsoever, so the way you are working with the notion of set here belongs to the realm of what mathematicians call [Naïve Set Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_set_theory#Paradoxes_in_early_set_theory), as opposed to [Axiomatic Set Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory).

One of the big differences between Naïve and Axiomatic Set Theory is that in the former one usually has no restriction on the ability of creating sets from "properties", usually formulated in ordinary language (say, English) as opposed to a [formal (first-order and finitary) language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language); this is, in Naïve Set Theory, given a property $P$ one can create the "set" $Y = \{ x : x \text{ has property }P \} $. People realized quite quickly that this kind of constructions were dangerous as they lead to [serious contradictions and paradoxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_set_theory#Paradoxes_in_early_set_theory), and this was one of the reasons why an axiomatic treatment of Set Theory started to take place.

So to answer your question, the fact that you obtain that $X \in X$ in your argument stems from defining the collection $X$ outside the formalism of Axiomatic Set Theory and then bringing in the Mathematics by claiming that such a collection is indeed a well-defined mathematical object (which is not), namely a set.